# A way to drag segues around to make Storyboard look nice?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I am working with Storyboard in XCode 6.1.1 and some of my segues go across the storyboard behind other views, making the storyboard look really sloppy. I was wondering if there is a way to drag segues around the storyboard, giving them joints or something so they wouldn't pass behind other views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Just drag your Scenes around in such a way so that it looks likes nodes in a graph.